# sqlite intersecting fulltext result with the normal index

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search

I have two tables: osm and osm_fulltext. The second table is a full text index and the first one is a usual table. Both have a record with id = 732048494

```
sqlite> SELECT objectid FROM osm where objectid=732048494;
732048494

sqlite> SELECT objectid FROM osm_fulltext where objectid MATCH 732048494;
732048494
```

But when I intersect results, I get nothing:

```
SELECT objectid 
   FROM osm_fulltext 
WHERE objectid MATCH 732048494 

   INTERSECT 

SELECT objectid 
   FROM osm 
WHERE objectid=732048494;
```

sqlite>

Is intersection supposed to work work on different types of storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTS tables store all their data as text, so your ID gets returned as a string, which is not the same as a number:

```
> SELECT 42 INTERSECT SELECT 42;
42
> SELECT 42 INTERSECT SELECT '42';
```

You could convert the ID into a number:

```
SELECT CAST(objectid AS NUMBER) FROM osm_fulltext
```

but for an ID to be used to search table records it would be a better idea to use the [implicit docid column](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_3):

```
INSERT INTO osm_fulltext(docid, whatever) VALUES(732048494, 'hello');
SELECT * FROM osm_fulltext WHERE docid = 732048494;
```